# Analysis: Basic Sequence Proof

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Prove that, if $\left\{a_n\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to A, then $\left\{|a_n|\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to |A|. Is the converse true?

Comment: what have you done so far ?

Comment: Well, I says, since $\left\{a_n\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\to A$, then for ever $\epsilon > 0$, there is $N\in J$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $|a_n - A|<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tip: $$||a_n|-|A||\leq|a_n-A|$$

so if $|a_n-A|<\epsilon$...

The converse was already given

Comment: Ooh. So... 

Since $\left\{ a_n \right\}$ converges to A, we have, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there is $N\in J$ such that for $n\geq N$, we have $|a_n - A| < \epsilon$. Since $||a_n| - |A|| \leq |a_n - A| < \epsilon$...... We have that $\left\{|a_n|\right\}\to |A|$. (...?)

Comment: Yep, you got it.

Comment: Thanks! I knew it had to be something pretty obvious, and probably to do with that inequality. I have no idea why inequalities always mess me up.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $a_n=(-1)^n$, then $|a_n|=1$, hence convergent but $a_n$ is oscillating.

Comment: This answers **exactly** what was asked. Why the downvote?

Comment: @Timbuc Thanks I am also wondering the reason for downvote.

Comment: I'd upvote you both but I can't yet. :/ Thank you for the counter example on the converse statement.

Comment: Didn't downvote myself, but I think it's getting downvoted because it answers the half of what he asks that is "hidden" at the end.

Answer (score 1):

No. Try $a_n=(-1)^n $. $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ $

Comment: This answers **exactly** what was asked. Why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote it. I don't have enough reputation to do so! But it only answers the question of "Is the converse true" and doesn't address the proof, so I think that's why? (It's still helpful, I wouldn't have downvoted it...)